# Is real projective space a manifold with boundary?

Tags: differential-geometry, projective-space

So real projective space,
$$\mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{R}) \simeq \mathbb{S}^n/\pm,$$
and the upper half-sphere can also be visualized (via bijection) as the upper hemisphere with half of the boundary circle (i.e. $x_i\geq0$). Is the upper hemisphere with half of the boundary circle a manifold with boundary?

This is briefly described in this stackexchange question: [Does the real projective space $\mathbb{R}P^n, n \geq 1$ have a boundary?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1947216/does-the-real-projective-space-mathbbrpn-n-geq-1-have-a-boundary). However, the answers there say that it isn't a manifold with boundary which makes me really confused. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: also half of the boundary is glued to half of the boundary in the hemisphere model, so it is not really a boundary in the quotient

Comment: But it's not half of the boundary circle, because the endpoints of that half-circle are glued together.

Comment: I see! That makes a lot of sense. So the quotient of a manifold with boundary isn't necessarily one with boundary. Thanks!

Comment: That may be true, but the case here is that the quotient of a manifold by a symmetry group is a manifold. There aren't any examples of manifolds with boundary (except in the sense that every manifold is a manifold with boundary, which happens to have the empty set as its boundary).

Answer (score 2):

Remember that a *manifold with boundary* is a topological space $M$ which is locally homeomorphic to either $\mathbb R^n$ or the half-space $\mathbb H^n:=\{(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in\mathbb R^n:x_1\ge0\}$. Then, one can let the *boundary* $\partial M$ of $M$ to be the set of points $p\in M$ such that there are no neighborhoods $U\ni p$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$. Thus, being a manifold (or, equivalently $\partial M=\emptyset$) can be seen as a *property* of a manifold with boundary $M$.

For any point $[p]\in \mathbb{RP}^n=\mathbb S^n/\sim$, the neighborhood $U=\{[q]\in\mathbb{RP}^n:p\cdot q\ne 0\}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$, where $U$ is well-defined since $p\cdot q\ne0$ iff $p\cdot(-q)\ne0$ for $p,q\in \mathbb S^n$. Indeed, choosing $p_1,\dots,p_n\in\mathbb S^n$ such that $p,p_1,\dots,p_n$ are mutually orthogonal, then there is a homomorphism to the open ball in $\mathbb R^n$
$$U\to B_1(0):[q]\mapsto(q\cdot p_1,\dots,q\cdot p_n),$$
where the representative $q\in[q]$ is chosen (uniquely) so that $q\cdot p>0$. Thus, $\mathbb{RP}^n$ is a manifold, i.e., has no boundary.